# App shows (Unreleased) even after rolling it out to production

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I recently rolled out an app which was under the beta testing from my google play console. but still when I am opening the app link. It shows as (Unreleased).
Please help!

Comment: This sort of question is best addressed to Google Play console support, who you can reach from the help icon "?" on the Play console

Comment: yes i did that ! and i got the reply from them .. thank you ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Note from google play support

> Updating an app usually takes a few hours, however sometimes it can take around 48 hours.